# Can't access to phpmyadmin - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I know there are many questions about this but strangely they didn't help me.
I've followed [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-secure-phpmyadmin-on-ubuntu-16-04) guide because I want to use phpMyAdmin on Ubuntu 16.04. I succesfully installed phpMyAdmin (in the process I've been asked to enter a password and I entered 'abcdef', then it asked me to re-enter the password and I inserted again 'abcdef').

Everything seemed good but when I go to localhost/phpmyadmin I see mySQL login form and I tried to access with username=root and password=abcdef but I keep getting this error message: `#1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`.

Answer (score 0):

Well in that case you can try resetting your password:

1. restart mysqld --skip-grant-tables option. ...
2. Connect to the mysqld server with this command:
3. shell>

   ```
   mysql
   ```

Issue the following statements in the mysql client. ...

4. mysql>

   ```
   UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('MyNewPass') -> WHERE User='root';
   ```
5. mysql>

   ```
   FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
   ```

Comment: I've followed this question: http://superuser.com/questions/603026/mysql-how-to-fix-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost. But at point number 2 of the accepted answer ("mysql -u root mysql") I still get the same error message